# Call function that's within ngAfterViewInit from outside ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, typescript

As the title suggests, I'm trying to call a function that is within ngAfterViewInit from outside of it. I can't move the function as it uses HTML elements that are only available once ngAfterViewInit has fired.

So, ideally this would work (but it doesn't):

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  --stuff--
  function foo() {
    --do stuff--
  }
}

public DoSomething() {
  --more stuff--
  foo();
}
```

Comment: Try to rephrase question... hard to undestand u

Comment: You could declare the function outside the scope of `ngAfterViewInit`. How does that sound?

Comment: I can't do that @OctavianMărculescu as the function relies on ngAfterViewInit having fired. If I try outside everything becomes undefined or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `this` keyword in the function, you'll want an arrow function:

```js
foo?: () => void;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  --stuff--
  this.foo = () => {
    //`this` refers to the component
    --do stuff--
  }
}

public DoSomething() {
  --more stuff--
  if (this.foo) this.foo();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Chris

Answer (score 0):

Make the reference to the function available outside of `ngAfterViewInit`

```
@Component()
export class SomeComponent {
 foo: Function;
 
 ngAfterViewInit() {
  // if you need to preserve the 'this' context simply use a lambda instead.
  this.foo = function() {
   // do things.
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mikkel, that seems to work (well I have to do: foo!: Function;) however how do I then call foo? this.foo doesn't appear to do anything and this.foo() gives an error saying it's not a function?

Comment: `this.foo` won't be defined until after ngAfterViewInit has been called. The specifics of how you can manage the timing in your component depends on what you are doing.